# Array modifier questions from a beginner

Tags: modifiers

I am following a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emT-CL957HE
Around 19:30, how does he turn off the array modifier for the duplicate? No matter what I do, they seem to share the same behaviour ie shadow the parent - can't figure out how he did it in the video.

Some other questions:

-What is the significance of Ctrl-L (at 18.30 and 20:00) and when is it used? I can't find any good info on the net that can provide a good example of the usage especially in the above context.
-What is the purpose of clicking Apply? Is there something that is irreversible once Apply is clicked?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

19:30 He basically duplicate the set of windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and then proceeded to deleting the array modifier that was copied during the duplicate fuction.

18:30 Ctrl L - It's basically a quick method to select a mesh and all it's joined elements. This is extremely useful if you have multiple sub-meshes joined together to form the main object. Sometimes you may want to select that one sub-mesh to apply a material or hide it temporarily.

Applying a modifier makes it permanent and irreversible. However you can undo it if it's still within the undo range. Usually you will want to apply modifier at the end of the modeling process.

[image]

**Extra Note**

Personally, I usually just hit <kbd>L</kbd>, this works in UV editor mode too when you want to select a UV island.

Comment: There is a difference between `L` and `Ctrl-L`, in edit mode (or uv mode in image editor) - `L` will select items linked to what is under the cursor while `Ctrl-L` will select items linked to the current selection. For completeness -  In object mode `L` is for "Make Local" and `Ctrl-L` is "Make Links". In the graph editor `L` will select all points on the active curve. In the node editor `Shift-L` will select nodes connected to the output of selected nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1.) He just duplicates the object and turns off the array modifier, then rotates it 90°, duplicates it again... It has nothing to do with parenting.

2.) With CTRL+L you can make links, that means you can copy (link) e.g. all modifiers from one object to another. I think in the video he just mistyped.

3.) He needed to click apply because otherwise the error you saw in the video would happen. It's not actually an error, by joining the object with the modifier to the object without the modifier, the modifier gets lost. So he has to apply it first. Once applied the array modifier as well as all other modifiers can't be restored indeed. If you fear that, make a copy to another layer first, then apply.

Comment: No. 2 is wrong. Ctrl L "make links" only work in object mode. He invoked Ctrl L in edit mode which is different.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the solution to (1) - I should make a duplicate first, then select the original array in Object mode and click "Apply" to the original array. I will then lose the ability to change the modifier settings to the original array. Next I select the duplicate, the modifier is still on for that duplicate and I can modify the number of copies for the duplicate. So, clicking "Apply" in this context helps me to separate the modifiers betw the original array and the duplicate.

Comment: For (3) the order of joining is important as per https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110810165839AAnZR0K but I am wondering as per Bortran's comments, whether clicking "Apply" will mean that the modifier of the first object will never be overridden.